# Vuex plugin + TypeScript. Error: Wrong state in store.subscribe

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I try use Vuex + TypeScript and wrote simple Vuex plugin:

```
const cartPlugin: Plugin<RootState> = (store) => {
    store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
        if (/^cart\/.+$/.test(mutation.type)) {
            storage.set('cart', state.cart.cart);
        }
    });
};
```

And TypeScript return error: `13:33 Property 'cart' does not exist on type 'RootState'.`:

```
    11 |   store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
    12 |     if (/^cart\/.+$/.test(mutation.type)) {
  > 13 |       storage.set('cart', state.cart.cart);
       |                                 ^
    14 |     }
    15 |   });
    16 | };
```

But actually it has property cart (this code work if use js instead ts):

```
const store: StoreOptions<RootState> = {
    modules: {
       catalog,
       cart,
    },
    strict: true,
    plugins: [cartPlugin],
};
```

and module `cart` has property `cart`:

```
export const state = (): CartState => {
    const cart = storage.get('cart') || [];
    return {
        cart,
    };
};
```

[Full code](https://gitlab.com/icrazyk/shop/blob/feature-typescript-stackoverflow/src/store/index.ts)

======== UPDATE ========

I added RootState description, and it`s working but looks like temporary workaround. Or no, who know? :)

```
import { CartState } from '@/store/cart/types';

export interface RootState {
    cart: CartState;
};
```

Comment: Your actual RootState type is empty: https://gitlab.com/icrazyk/shop/blob/feature-typescript-stackoverflow/src/store/types.ts ...  so it does not have a cart property...

Comment: Yes, but `state` in `store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {...})` has  modules: state.moduleName.moduleProperty . But TypeSctipt don`t knows about it.

Comment: May be it need declare. But how? `RootState` describe Root State, not modules.